# Can I make a flashable zip executing commands?

Tags: cyanogenmod, twrp, scripts, supersu, oneplus-3

I'm using cm13 on my OnePlus 3, along with systemless SuperSu and suhide. When I update cm (often), I need to flash both SuperSu and suhide. The problem is that cm comes with root access and when updating, makes a su directory in /system/bin/su that suhide detects so that it won't install. I need to delete that directory in between of the flashes, and I would like to make a script that does that for me when i flash it so that I can flash all files together on update using CyanDelta. I know that this is possible because I have seen other zips that execute command scripts as i flash them.

Answer (score 0):

Find an empty flashable package somewhere; edit `META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script` and add `delete_recursive("/path/to/your/directory");` to remove the directory in question.

(On second thought, is it really necessary to make a flashable zip for this single purpose? If your phone has TWRP recovery available, why not just use its built-in file manager?)

Comment: OP could also make their own flashable ZIP, with the structure **META-INF/com/google/android**, create an **update-binary** file inside the last directory and write `#!/sbin/sh`, followed by `mount -o rw /partition_name` and `rm -rf /path/to/your/directory` inside the file. Finally, just zip the **META-INF** folder and here's the flashable ZIP.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Wow, I don't know you could actually write `update-binary` yourself (the ones I've seen are mostly in unreadable format, except for SuperSU's). Thanks for the info.

Comment: In fact, the classical **update-binary** is a compiled binary, just like a **sh**. The workaround for those which want more flexibility is just to write the file as a simple shell script, and by doing so you can also ignore the **updater-script**.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman How can a binary be replaced by a script? It sounds weird to me that this is even feasible.

Comment: Ah, I don't know the procedure employed by a recovery. Still, if you don't believe me, you're free to unpack a CyanogenMod flashable ZIP and examine its update-binary. For instance, the one I analyzed began with the bytes `7F 45 4C 46`, which stand for `.ELF`, identifying the file as a compiled binary.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the reason I would like a flashable zip is that i update my phone often, almost every day, and I would like to update everything by just pressing update in CyanDelta.

Comment: I did what you said, but when I flash my zip, TWRP tells me that it could not find  META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary. What should I do, edit the update-binary file in some way? I'm doing this using TextEdit on my mac, and when I try to edit the file it just shows a bunch of nonsense. May I ask for someone to make this zip for me, just a file to delete /system/xbin/su?

Comment: I uploaded what I've packaged onto my [AndroidFileHost](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=529152257862667611) - try it out. If `/system/xbin/su` is a directory rather than a file, replace `delete` with `delete_recursive` in `updater-script`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I'm now able to update my phone without any hassle :D